# Dump all tables in a DBContext

Tags: entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I have a DBContext for an SQL Server database what has over 350 tables and it's a bit messy so I want to dump all datasets in it to JSON files. I already have a JSON extension `Save()` that will just dump any object to JSON so I want to use DBSet.ToList().Save(DBSet.TableName) to dump all the records into a specific file.
I have this code:

```
var entities = DB.Model.GetEntityTypes();
foreach (var entity in entities)
{
    string cleanTitle = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().Aggregate(entity.GetTableName, (current, c) => current.Replace(c, '_'));
    string filename = Path.Combine(folderJSON.FullName, cleanTitle + ".json");
    entity.<Needs something here>.Save(filename);
}
```

It's just the  part that needs to be solved now. Or am I using the wrong approach here?
Yeah, I know this can become messy but the whole project is messy already and I have to clean things up. Having the data as JSON allows me to get more insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better here to dynamically invoke static method which do the job:

```cs
public static class ContextExtensions
{
    static MethodInfo _saveDbSetMethodInfo =
        typeof(ContextExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(SaveDbSet), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    static void SaveDbSet<T>(DbContext context, string fileName)
        where T : class
    {
        var items = context.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().ToList();
        items.Save(fileName); // or any other operation
    }

    public static void SaveDatabase(this DbContext context, string destinationFolder)
    {
        var entities = context.Model.GetEntityTypes();
        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            var cleanTitle = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().Aggregate(entity.GetTableName(), (current, c) => current.Replace(c, '_'));
            string filename = Path.Combine(destinationFolder, cleanTitle + ".json");

            _saveDbSetMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(entity.ClrType).Invoke(null, new object[] { context, filename });
        }
    }
}
```